# Temporarily wire a dimmer light to an outlet

Tags: electrical

I have a 19’ high ceiling with a poor hanging light. I have purchased a new light but we aren’t sure of the effect 5 LEDs will have in various times. I would to wire the light temporarily to an outlet in the room a few days before the electrician comes to install so we can try 2-3 types of bulbs and wattage. Is this possible or safe to do? Nothing else will be on in room

Comment: What size/type of ceiling box is the existing light attached to?

Comment: It’s to a bow in the ceiling where the new light will be. I just want to bypass hooking it up and test it at various times since the electrician will only be here to install and leave, the cost of Gothenburg back out just to change bulbs would be prohibitive

Comment: What *size* is that box? Can you post photos of it with the box opened up please? (Turn the breaker off first!)

Comment: it seems to me that you could fit a lead to the lamp and plug that into the outlet.  I'm not sure how code-legal that would be, there are some exemptions for testing, (which seems to be your motive)

Comment: Under the NEC rules It would be a code violation to wire a receptacle with a dimmer.  if you are talking about a lighting outlet a vast majority of the US allows homeowners to replace devices like switches / dimmers. Providing your location would be helpful. To tell the truth if I was setting up a temp thing like this for testing I probably would not pay attention to code for the testing but make sure to return the circuit to the original condition after testing.  Where in the world do you live? It may be that your electrical code doesn’t define this as a violation like the NEC.

Comment: I cannot post photos of the light box opened up as it is unreachable. The outlet box I would access is just a normal outlet box